# using bfg or filter-repo, I want to replace text in specific file

Tags: bfg-repo-cleaner, git-filter-repo

my git repo has above files with directory,

- service-a

  - app.config
- service-b

  - app.config

I want to replace the text in service-a/app.config, not service-b/app.config using bfg or filter-repo.

but those looks don't support it. How can I do that?

thanks